# Lync 2013 SDK - Change meeting view - C#

Tags: c#, lync, lync-2013, lync-client-sdk

How can I change the meeting view using Lync 2013 SDK (either Lync Automation or in UI Suppression mode).

I have searched a lot but didn't found anything that can let me know how to achieve this programmatically. I am using C# language but example in any language (as long as it uses Lync 2013 SDK) will help me.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to change meeting view with the Lync 2013 SDK in any way.  The you can do is overlay with your own windows but that's about it.

If you wish to redo the meeting view you can use the new [Skype Web SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/websdk/skypewebsdk).  This will give you more control of the screen layout than the Lync SDK.  The downsides are:

- Not released yet, only available in public review only.
- No meeting content support (yet?) - i.e. shared applications / whiteboard / etc.
- Setup more involved.

If you really want to have ultimate control you could use both Lync SDK and Skype WEB SDK combined to give you the all the bits, although that would be a lot of work.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs @Shane Powell. Let me try Skype Web SDK alongside Lync SDK. I will post my review after that.